# Core Data Store migration issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Getting below error while migrating CoreData to a new version. I am using Automatic migration of CoreData. My CoreData stores document and it seems when data size is large this starts happening. Is it that Core Data will not be able to migrate large data using automatic migration. After crash when i check the documents directory it shows following files:

- Documents/.appname.sqlite.migrationdestination_xxxx
- Documents/.appname.sqlite.migrationdestination_xxxx-shm
- Documents/.appname.sqlite.migrationdestination_xxxx-wal
- Documents/appname.sqlite Documents/appname.sqlite-shm
- Documents/appname.sqlite-wal

**Error:**

> The database at
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/782EE7A8-729F-429C-84AF-501B5F866592/Documents/DocViewer.sqlite
>   is corrupted.  SQLite error code:11, 'database disk image is
>   malformed'

Here is my implementation of persistentStore:

```
 - (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
    {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"DocViewer.sqlite"];
    //738001
    NSDictionary *options = @{
                              NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                              NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                              NSSQLitePragmasOption:@{@"journal_mode":@"DELETE"}
                              };
    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])
    {
        ADLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);



        //abort();
    }

    storeURL = nil;
    options = nil;

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Comment: Why are you changing `journal_mode`? One of the main purposes of the default journal mode is to avoid corruption.

Comment: I have tried with and without journal_mode and result is same as above error. It seems that i have large binary data so automatic lightweight migration wont be possible i have to go for mapping model with migration in parts. Is there any other way apart from mapping model for migration.

Comment: We tried for mapping model migration but for large data this also fails. Now how can we achieve chunk migration from mapping model. Is there any tutorial on this. I am much worried about relationships in different entities.